# Using both Visual Studio 2010 & Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2010 for develop the .Net projects. Is it possible to use both Visual Studio 2010 as well as Visual Studio 2013 to develop the project ? else we can use only one version.

**P.S**: Already I am using Office 2010 & 2013 in my system.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible for many types of Visual Studio projects.  The feature that allows a project file to be used by multiple versions of Visual Studio is known as round tripping

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/28/round-tripping-with-visual-studio-11.aspx

This was added in 2012 and hence applies to 2010 projects as well.  Not all project support this but the main ones do.

Comment: If the project created in VS2010, then we use VS2012 or VS2013 for additional enhancement, do we face any issue because of version change.?

Comment: I own a Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate license. Can I install VS2013 using that same license, or would I have to shell out more? If not VS2013, can I still use my 2010 license for VS2012?